# Specify README to show in gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

I have forked a project in gitlab. After cloning my fork, I did something like this:

```
mv README.md README-OLD.md
touch README.md
echo "some content for my new readme" >> README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "New readme"
git push origin master
```

In GitLab, I refresh my project's page expecting to see the new README.md contents, but instead, I see the old document in parsed form, with the new document only showing up in the file list. (In other words, my changes show up, but GitLab still chooses to put the old, renamed document front and center, in contradiction of my wishes.)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `git status` return? Does your commit show up in Gitlab? Also, isn't it `git push origin master`

Comment: Good points -- I have now edited the question to address them. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried removing the old README entirely?

Comment: Removing it entirely allows GitLab to show the correct README.md content. Re-introducing the README-OLD.md file brings the buggy behavior back. It makes me believe that perhaps GitLab simply goes with the first file (in alphabetical order) that contains "README" in the title. Anyhow, thanks for the help. Your change "worked" for all intents.

Comment: If I only have a file called `README-OLD.md` in a folder, GitLab doesn't display the contents.  I was hoping it would so I could have some flexibility with the filename.  But it seems like (with the exception of your issue) the file has to be called readme.md (case insensitive.)